# ExtJs 3.4 : Remove border of a fieldset

Tags: javascript, extjs, fieldset

I have an ExtJs fieldset.

```
{
                xtype : 'fieldset',
                layout : 'hbox',

                defaults : {
                    layout : 'hbox',
                    labelAlign : 'left',
                    border : false,
                    frame : false
                },
                items : [ {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    id : 'idDrop',
                    text : '',
                    width : 120,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        //background : 'yellow',
                        color : 'black',
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        border: '1px solid black',
                        'font-weight':'bold'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    text : '',
                    id : 'idPickup',
                    width : 120,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        //background : 'green',
                        color : 'black',
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        border: '1px solid black',
                        'font-weight':'bold'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    text : '',
                    id : 'idMix',
                    width : 120,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        //background : 'blue',
                        color : 'black',
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        border: '1px solid black',
                        'font-weight':'bold'
                    }
                } ]
            }
```

I've tried to remove the frame of this fieldset as following.

```
defaults : {
                    layout : 'hbox',
                    labelAlign : 'left',
                    border : false,
                    frame : false
                }
```

But no luck.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: use a container instead

Answer (score 5):

The properties in the [defaults](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldSet-cfg-defaults) configuration object will be applied to all **items** of the fieldset, not the fieldset itself.

In order to remove the border there, just set `border: false` on the fieldset:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    border: false,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i copied my code into this fiddle.it works fine.but it doesn't work in my application.why ?

Comment: That's hard to tell without insight into your application. Maybe it's an issue with your CSS? Try inspecting the fieldset with Firebug/Chrome DevTools. The fieldset should have a class `x-fieldset-noborder`. If that's the case, are there any other CSS classes/inline styles which apply a border?

Comment: yeah it has .x-fieldset-noborder {
    border:0px none transparent;
}

Comment: In that case, if your fieldset still has a border, there must be another style somewhere which overrides the border style again. You should be able to see which style actually sets the border in your DOM inspector tool.